# MDX Operation, Syntax correct, Values = NULL

Tags: null, ssas, mdx

I Need to do the following calculation in mdx (i hope the code is straightforward, if clarification is needed please tell)

```
([Orders].[Customer].CurrentMember, [Measures].[InvoiceAmount]) / (Root([Orders]), [Measures].[InvoiceAmount])
```

but all I'm getting is NULL values,
can anybody see what is wrong?

Comment: A couple of questions: Can you confirm that you have values for ([Orders].[Customer].CurrentMember, [Measures].[InvoiceAmount])?
Do you have an All member for Orders?  If not, what is the default member set to?

Comment: Yes i do have Values for it, and i don't really know where for weather i have an All member for Orders

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve so that you think `Root([Orders])` is needed? As I assume @mmarie intended to suggest, would `([Orders].[Customer].CurrentMember, [Measures].[InvoiceAmount]) / ([Orders].[Customer].[All], [Measures].[InvoiceAmount])` not give you the result that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my question has been answered,
thanks to you all for your great help
[MDX Operation, Syntax correct, Values = NULL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/109d289c-6636-40f8-b382-06cc055bc7ba/mdx-operation-syntax-correct-values-null?prof=required)